# Unit test failing on clicking on view included in layout via "include tag"

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

**MY PROBLEM:**

My current unit test "onClickSkipButtonAndVerifyAppExists" is failing because I'm not able to click on the skip button which is within the include layout="@layout/navigation_bar". The layout for it is basically a skip button on the left and a next button on the right. I'm suspecting that the reason why it's failing it's because it is not able to click on a view from an include tag.

I have the following scenario:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class, true, true) {

        @Override
        protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterActivityFinished() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void onClickSkipButtonAndVerifyAppExists() {
        onView(withId(R.id.navigation_bar_skip)).perform(click());
    }

}
```

Also, my XML layout file for that specific test is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ignite="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_outer_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_inner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_bar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                android:background="@color/header_footer">


                <com.digitalturbine.igniteui.view.DynamicLayoutToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    ignite:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    ignite:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/toolbarBackground"
                    ignite:layoutType="left_two_line_title_w_icon"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_container"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/wizard_disabled_overlay"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_bar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <include layout="@layout/navigation_bar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/full_screen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SUGGESTIONS:**

If anybody can provide insights and not think that this is the actual problem, please do. I tried multiple things before concluding that this might be the problem, but again, any thoughts are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First you should manually check if skip button is shown and it works (you can click on it). By the look of your XML code, frame layout *full_screen_content* is going over bottom bar so that could cause a problem.

If the button is visible and clickable, check again if id *navigation_bar_skip* is correct. Or you can try to use withText method instead of withId...

Also, you don't need to override methods afterActivityLaunched and afterActivityFinished. Test will not start until activity is ready. If you want this pause, you can put it inside @Test method. And for initialization, you should use @Before and @After, that will run before and after every test.

Comment: It was actually due to MainActivity class. One of its function was not executed properly hence the issue that I experienced.